# mediaPlayer doesn't play

Tags: java, android, media-player, splash-screen

I am trying to build a splash screen with music in the background, but the music doesn't play.

Here is my code:

```
    package com.example.thebasicseries;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;  

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    MediaPlayer logoMusic;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        logoMusic = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.techno );
        Thread logoTimer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(5000);
                    Intent menuIntent = new Intent("com.example.thebasicseries.MENU");
                    startActivity(menuIntent);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally{
                    finish();
                }
            }

        };
        logoTimer.start();
        logoMusic.release();
    }
```

There isn't any error message showing before or after running the app.

Comment: You need logoMusic.play() to play music. I only see create and release.

Comment: there is not .play() as i tried. it was working before but i don't understand why it is stop working, maybe because i've been playing around the code.

Comment: I suggest you use AsyncTask for background music playing in its own thread - see this sample [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16338215/4123144)

Answer (score 0):

LOL, you created the MP :

`logoMusic = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.techno )`;

But never play it :

```
logoMusic.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

better you cut particular portion for your splash screen from video and use it as like gif image it will work

Answer (score 0):

i have got it work!

```
    package com.example.thebasicseries;


import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    MediaPlayer logoMusic;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        logoMusic = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.techno );
        logoMusic.start();
        Thread logoTimer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(5000);
                    Intent menuIntent = new Intent("com.example.thebasicseries.MENU");
                    startActivity(menuIntent);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally{
                    finish();
                }
            }

        };
        logoTimer.start();

    }
    @Override //so i just create an onPause method and release my song

    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        logoMusic.release(); //while it is onPause i release the song
    }


}
```